# How to perform String operations in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

Input:

```json
{
  "Remarks":"COMMENTS:(87) Test Comments"
}
```

Expecting Output is below:

```json
{
  "Remarks" : "C(87): TestComments"
  "Id" : 87
}
```

I want to replace **COMMENTS:(87)** string with **C(87):** and need to get **87** in brackets and print the same in separate attribute **"Id"**.

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **split** function along with **modify** transformation in order to split the string by opening and closing parentheses, and then combine the desired substrings by using **concat** function. At the last step get rid of the auxiliary elements through use of **remove** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "str0": "=split('\\(', @(1,Remarks))",
      "str1": "=split('\\)', @(1,str0))",
      "str2": "@(1,str1[1])",
      "Remarks": "=concat('C(',@(1,str2[0]),'):',@(1,str2[1]))",
      "Id": "@(1,str2[0])"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "str*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

[image]